# How to add text and picture in expandable list

Tags: android-listview

I am trying to learn Android by developing an app based on web site (eflore.fr), using the same database and photos embedded in the app. For this, I am using the android expandable listview example at the [http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/expandablelistview/android-expandablelistview-example/ site](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/expandablelistview/android-expandablelistview-example/) modified to be compatible with the database and it works well. I have 2 questions :

1. How to add a textview at the top of the main activity ? A textview in activity_main.xml or group.xml or row.xml is either a mistake or is not visible.
2. Is it possible to put text an image in the child list ? 
   Thanks for help

Comment: Unclear. `How to add a textview at the top of the main activity?` Do you want to add a TextView on top of the ListView? `Is it possible to put text an image in the child list?` If you mean an image on every row, yes, it is.

Comment: Sorry, firstly i want to had a textview on the top of main_activity (it was to show items selected in the listview.

Comment: and secondly put text and image (it is ok for text but not for image)  on every row of the child list

Comment: You can easily design your layout to contain a TextView on top of your ListView. You can for sure add a custom row which contains an ImageView and a TextView, but a TextView which uses a compound drawable is more optimized. When filling the data from the adapter, add the compound drawable too.